# Error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'QTVisualContextRef'

Tags: objective-c

I am currently getting this error message in my header code, and I'm not sure as to why:

"Error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'QTVisualContextRef'"

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <QTKit/QTKit.h>
#import <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <CoreVideo/CoreVideo.h>


@interface MyRecorderController : NSObject {
    IBOutlet QTCaptureView *mCaptureView;

    IBOutlet NSPopUpButton *videoDevicePopUp;
    NSMutableDictionary *namesToDevicesDictionary;
    NSString *defaultDeviceMenuTitle;

    CVImageBufferRef mCurrentImageBuffer;
    QTCaptureDecompressedVideoOutput       *mCaptureDecompressedVideoOutput;

    QTVisualContextRef  qtVisualContext;    // the context the movie is playing in

    // filters for CI rendering
    CIFilter            *colorCorrectionFilter; // hue saturation brightness control through one CI filter
    CIFilter            *effectFilter;          // zoom blur filter
    CIFilter            *compositeFilter;       // composites the timecode over the video
    CIContext           *ciContext;

    QTCaptureSession *mCaptureSession;
    QTCaptureMovieFileOutput *mCaptureMovieFileOutput;
    QTCaptureDeviceInput *mCaptureDeviceInput;

}

@end
```

In the examples I have seen through other code (e.g. [Cocoa Video Tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreVideo/CVProg_Tasks/CVProg_Tasks.html)) I have not seen any difference in their code to mine. If anyone would be able to point out as to how this error could have occurred that would be great.
Thanks heaps! :)

Comment: The file that describes 'QTVisualContextRef' is not included. I might think, that you miss something like '#include "QTVisualContextRef.h"'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are compiling as a 64-bit application, QTVisualContextRef is not available to you.   You'll need to compile the application as 32-bit.

Apple hasn't fully fleshed out QTKit to be 64-bit quite yet...

Answer (score 1):

That's a GCC error and it means the token `QTVisualContextRef` is not known to the compiler. It's a rather poor error message indeed. You need to add the correct `#import` that will teach the compiler about this type. It's part of the QuickTime framework, so you probably want

```
#import <QuickTime/QuickTime.h>
```

Comment: Yep, it's one of those errors that is immediately obvious after much experience with it, but maddingly unspecific when you're coding in Cocoa for the first time!

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately, doing so has not changed the situation (I included the framework as well). I am quite new to Objective-C, which doesn't help either! xD

Comment: Did you put this import at the top of the header? I just checked, `<QuickTime/QuickTime.h>` imports `<QuickTime/ImageCompression.h>` which defines `QTVisualContextRef`. If you put the import in the right spot, it should work. If it's not working, do you have a different error message?

Comment: Is it possible that `QTVisualContextRef` is new and you're using an older SDK that doesn't have it? You could also try importing `<QuickTime/ImageCompression.h>` directly to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: The base SDK I am using is 'Mac OS X 10.6'. That's the highest one I have. I tried the import, and no change. Perhaps it's something to do with the location of the framework? I might check that out.