# Extracting movie frames quickly in a 64-bit Cocoa app on Snow Leopard

Tags: performance, 64-bit, extract, frame, movie

I wrote a 64-bit Cocoa app on Snow Leopard that extracts individual frames
from a movie using the QuickTime API.  It uses [QTMovie currentFrameImage],
which unfortunately is very slow, as was pointed out here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843702/export-every-frame-from-a-movie-using-quicktime-api

Apple's developer site describes the following alternative method using
QTPixelBufferContextCreate with NewMovieFromProperties:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1443/_index.html

Using this approach, I wrote a 32-bit app that was able to extract the
frames at a much faster rate, but it appears that the API
(e.g. QTVisualContextRef) is not available to 64-bit apps, as was pointed
out here:

http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/html/quicktime-api@lists.apple.com/2009-01/msg00014.html

and here:

[Error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'QTVisualContextRef'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708257/error-expected-specifier-qualifier-list-before-qtvisualcontextref)

My app needs to be 64-bit, so I am seeking another alternative for extracting
frames quickly.  Has anyone accomplished this using the frameworks currently
available on Snow Leopard?

Edit:

I did not find a way to extract frames quickly on Snow Leopard, but I did find
a way to do it using AV Foundation on Lion.  AV Foundation has been available
for iOS, but it is new for Mac OS starting with Lion.  A good description of
how to extract frames quickly using AV Foundation can be found at [7twenty7com](http://www.7twenty7.com/blog/2010/11/video-processing-with-av-foundation).