# Scanning for QR Code in Quicktime Files in MacOS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, avfoundation, qr-code

The only information I've been able to find in QR Code scanning for the new AVFoundation-supported scanning is for iOS, and specifically using the camera.

I need to be able to scan for a QR Code in pre-recorded video Quicktime files.

I'm not even quite sure where to begin looking for this.

Basically, I need to open a video file, scan the video file for QR Codes embedded in the frames of the pre-recorded video, and then produce the results.

EDIT:

I attempted a bit more on this. I tried running some code for compiling on MacOS instead of iOS and I get the usual errors, telling me most of it is only supported by iOS.  I can't seem to feed the QRCode framework anything in MacOS.  There must be a way to do... Anyone out there come across this?

Comment: What have you tried already? All the steps above are rather simple to find out by using google...

Comment: I've googled this and found nothing.  Everything I find is specifically for getting a camera feed and scanning live video on a phone.  I want to scan pre-recorded video on a desktop. I've tried looking at examples of what folks do in iOS, a few github projects, and seeing if I can derive a way to reconfigure it to work with video instead, but no luck.

Comment: For a start you can read a quicktime movie frame by frame and inspect the frames - a first hint and some ideas here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672348/extracting-movie-frames-quickly-in-a-64-bit-cocoa-app-on-snow-leopard

Comment: Looking into it now...  And note, I've already done this with ZXing, but the obj-c library was discontinued and I'm only just now learning that Apple has a framework for scanning barcodes.  So I'm trying to migrate over to that one, as I'm sure it has better support.